# Debian applications in a different language and unable to change

Tags: debian, gnome3, locale, display-settings

I recently had to reinstall GNOME on my Debian7 system, the reason being there was a problem with the older version.

Unfortunately, probably since I am in Belgium, it has installed part French, part English.  I don't fully understand why but things such as 'in-app' language is set to French but the system itself seems to be in English.  Even as I type in Chrome here it marks all english words as incorrect.

When I open Guake on start up these two lines appear before the input prompt:

```
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (fr_FR.utf8)
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (fr_FR.utf8)
```

When I go into settings to try and change it doesn't make a difference:
[image: Options all in French]
[image: Country and Language settings]
[image: Changing to english]
[image: Requests a restart of session]

Even after going through this process (restarting the session and the computer) it is still French.

Any help is appreciated guys, thank you!